# Django ninja token authentication with djoser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser, django-ninja

I have implemented CRUD with Django Ninja framework, but now I want auth in my app,
I had installed and config Djoser, so now I can generate tokens, but I don't know how to verify in my CRUD's

```py
class AuthBearer(HttpBearer):
    def authenticate(self, request, token):
        if token == "supersecret":
            return token

@api.get("/bearer", auth=AuthBearer())
def bearer(request):
    return {"token": request.auth}
```

I shoud able to check token inside "AuthBearer" function, but I don't know how

my repo ([link](https://github.com/arsalanses/ham-radio-logger/blob/master/logs/api/v1.py))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so basically you have to extend Ninja's HttpBearer class and implement authenticate method, which will accept request and token as parameters. This method returns None if the user is not authenticated, and a string which will be populated in request.auth if the user is authenticated. Usually this string will be the username so you can use it in all your endpoints.
Something like this (I am using PyJWT for token decoding):

```
import jwt
from ninja.security import HttpBearer

class AuthBearer(HttpBearer):
    def authenticate(self, request, token):
        try:
            #JWT secret key is set up in settings.py
            JWT_SIGNING_KEY = getattr(settings, "JWT_SIGNING_KEY", None)
            payload = jwt.decode(token, JWT_SIGNING_KEY, algorithms=["HS256"])
            username: str = payload.get("sub")
            if username is None:
                return None
        except jwt.PyJWTError as e:
            return None

        return username
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example! How are you generate the encoded token though? Do you save these tokens in storage?